# Tab completion in Vim Commands

Tags: vim

When I type a command in Vim, for example opening a file, I start to type the file name, and I want to press Tab and have Vim autocomplete the name. However, when I press Tab, vim puts in `^I` for some reason.

How can I make Vim tab complete?

Comment: solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326627/vims-open-does-not-tab-complete-what-does

Comment: Solved also here: https://superuser.com/a/445607/361600

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The character which starts command-line completion defaults to <kbd>Tab</kbd> only when `nocompatible` is set. In Vi compatible mode it's <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd>.

This is documented in [:h cmdline-completion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-completion).

You can [`set nocompatible`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27compatible%27) in your .vimrc file to make it work as expected.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true anymore. It doesn't work for me on a Linux box with Vim 7.4.576.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do stuff like omni-completion, you can also open the command line in a window by typing `q:` in normal mode or `CTRL-F` as you're typing your command.

[image: command line view]

Same goes with `/finding_patterns` with `q/` and `q?`