# Vim's :open does not tab complete, what does?

Tags: vim

Instead of tab completed file or directory names, I see `^I`

```
:open ./lib/^I^I^I
```

Is there another command that would offer tab completion, or perhaps another solution?

I'm considering replacing the following mapping with something that would use buffers, but want to keep tab completion.

```
map <C-O> :tabnew ./
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

That might be because `:open` is not the command you're looking for. Try `:edit` or `:e` for short. Also try `:help :open` and `:help :e` to see, what the commands do. `:e` has tab completion.

Comment: To know why `:open` is not the best command see here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2276

Answer (score 27):

Use `:enew` if you want to create a new empty buffer.

Use `:edit filename` if you want to edit a specific file in place of the current one.

Use `:new` if you want to create a new empty buffer in a new horizontal split window.

Use `:split filename` if you want to edit a specific file in a new horizontal split window.

Use `:vnew` if you want to create a new empty buffer in a new vertical split window.

Use `:vsplit filename` if you want to edit a specific file in a new vertical split window.

Use `:tabnew` if you want to create a new empty tab.

Use `:tabedit filename` if you want to edit a specific file in a new tab.

---

Use `:help :command` if you are unsure about its usage.

Answer (score 0):

:set wildcharm=<`tab`> for tab completion.

Comment: would you mind modifying the answer and add even small description